# Can you delete secret_token.rb after upgrading to rails 4.1 or >

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I see Rails 4.1 loads the rails secret token from secrets.yml, once I've upgraded is it safe to delete secret_token.rb then? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can. As stated here (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#config-secrets-yml), you should remove the file and use the `yml` approach.